# Some errors deploying Ruby on Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Regards!

I'm trying to deploy my application but the following errors are shown, however it works in my development environment.  Could anyone help me, please.

Thank you

```
2018-10-19T21:44:59.537471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 56071 -e production`
2018-10-19T21:45:05.502421+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-10-19T21:45:05.483819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390570+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': No such file to load -- classes/global/String.rb (LoadError)
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390589+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390591+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390592+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390594+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/lib/classes/nino_nino.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390596+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390635+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390637+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-10-19T21:45:05.390639+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/jobs/crea_planilla_ninonino_job.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

---

/app/lib/classes/nino_nino.rb starts like this:

```
    require 'classes/global/String'
    require 'classes/zip'
    require 'tempfile'

        module NinoNino
            class NinoNinoController < ApplicationController

                def crea_certificados(par)

                    session = {}
                    session["group_id"] = par["group_id"]

                    @anio = par["anio"].to_i
                    @mes = par["mes"].to_i
                    @municipio = par["municipio"]
                    @dias_mes = (JSON.parse par["dias_mes"]).collect {|e| e["value"]}
                    @genera_nino_nino = (par["genera_nino_nino"] == "true")
                    @genera_resumen = (par["genera_resumen"] == "true")
                    job_id = par["job_id"]

                    @format = par["format"]
                    (...)
```

classes/global/String:

```
class String
    def last_n_chars(len)
        self[-len..-1] || self
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you switch over to postgreSQL from SQLite? What about running `bundle install`? I'm not sure if you have already, but you'll also need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` or `heroku run rails db:migrate`.

Comment: Could you show the exact content of `/app/lib/classes/nino_nino.rb:1`? If I'd have to guess I'd say that it's a problem with the case sensitivity of the filesystem: it's looking for `String.rb`, but maybe it should be `string.rb` instead?